# How to redirect 404

Tags: redirect, hyperlink

For example in past my website look like this:
Example: www.mywebsite.com/keyword

Now look like this:
Example: www.mywebsite.com/search.php?q=keyword

How can i redirect people who search for a specific tag to my new link?

From "www.mywebsite.com/keyword" to "www.mywebsite.com/search.php?q=keyword"

I'm not so good with coding so based to my examples can somebody make the code that need to be inserted in htaccess file pls.

This are the examples of links:

OLD: www.mywebsite.com/keyword

NEW: www.mywebsite.com/search.php?q=keyword

Comment: @Cipiran: which web-server? The answer will be different depending upon which one you use.

Answer (score 0):

That redirecting is called **URL Rewriting**, and is usually done via a `.htaccess` file for Apache, or with magic if you're using Lighttpd.

I would take a look at this website, which more or less explains how to do it (assuming you're running Apache): http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/sitemanagement/urlrewriting.html

Comment: Don't use `.htaccess` if you've got access to the VirtualHost because it's wasteful of performance like it says near the top [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html).

Comment: What web server do you run then? @nickgrim, I use Lighty, so I don't even know much about all these `.htaccess` files myself.

Answer (score 0):

The specific details depend on the web server being used (IIS, Apache, etc.) but basically you could configure those to redirect to a specific web page and extract the keyword from the original URL and place it in the query string parameter list.

For example, in IIS you would do the following:

Start > Programs > Administrative Tools > Internet Services Manager
   Select your web site from the list and right-click to go Properties.
   The Custom Errors tab is where you will see a list of HTTP errors.
   Select the "404" page and "Edit Properties" to point this to a web page of your choosing.

The last step is where you will plug in your custom code that will handle the redirect.